# How to push a specific json object in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My data look like this:

[image]

and my code looks like this:

```js
    const navItemData = props.data.navigation_bar;
    let temporaryDrawers = [];

    if (navItemData) {
        for (let i = 0; i < navItemData.length; i++) {
            if (navItemData[i].object_type === 'temporary_drawer') {
                temporaryDrawers.push(navItemData[i]);

                // CODE HERE
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the log of my `temporaryDrawers` array:

[image]

I want to say in the `//CODE HERE` that:

```js
if (navigation_bar.content === data.key with the same name e.g. 'products')
then temporaryDrawers.push the array 'products'
```

and the result that I'm expecting is to get a `temporaryDrawers` array that looks like this:

[image]

This is my data structure:

```
{
  "website": {
    "navigation_bar": [
      {
        "object_type": "temporary_drawer",
        "title": "Products",
        "content": "products"
      },
      {
        "object_type": "temporary_drawer",
        "title": "Resources",
        "content": "resources"
      },
      {
        "object_type": "navigation_button",
        "title": "Pricing",
        "link": "/pricing"
      }
    ],
    "products": [
      {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "image": "/mockImage1.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "image": "/mockImage2.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "image": "/mockImage3.png"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "image": "/mockImage4.png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't insert screenshots, post real code. As of now, it is _impossible_ to answer you question because we cannot see the complete structure of your data. For example: Where is that `.key` property defined? It seems it's defined inside the items in `products`, but that's just guessing.

Comment: @David fixed it.

Comment: Please note that JSON refers to a *string format* of a JavaScript object. It looks like you are just working with JavaScript objects and not their JSON string representation, the JSON tag is not correct.

Comment: Your data (at the end) has a toplevel "website" property, which you never use in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can help.
You are dynamically creating a property that reflects the string under 'content'.
Next, you are using the same string as a key in the data object in order to attach a list to the created property

```
if (navItemData) {
  for (let i = 0; i < navItemData.length; i++) {
    if (navItemData[i].object_type === 'temporary_drawer') {
        const item = navItemData[i];
        temporaryDrawers.push({...item, [item.content]: props.data[item.content]});

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And is there a way to rename it to `'content'` at the same time?

Comment: sure.

temporaryDrawers.push({...item, content: props.data[item.content]});